# Can I share a copy of Adobe Standalone Flash Player?

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet, software, fair-use

As you all know by now, Flash is dead. However, people still want to play flash games. People used to be able to download the standalone adobe flash player to keep playing games flash games, but apparently they've removed the download page for it.

I still have a copy of the flash player and would like to share it with Flash game fans. I won't be profiting off of it, and I will credit Adobe (it's called the Adobe Flash Player after all, so it's impossible not to give them credit). Would it be legal for me to distribute the Flash Player online?

This is a United States question by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Copyright does not have exemptions for obsolete works, use with credit, or non-commercial use. Depending on the purpose for the distribution, this could be [fair use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), but it is unlikely that a court will consider this fair use when the only reason is for other people to be able to play games.

Perhaps you could try contacting Adobe; it's possible, albeit highly unlikely, that they will give you a license to distribute the Flash Player.

This isn't directly relevant to the legal aspect of copying Adobe's Flash Play, but to answer the underlying issue of legally playing Flash games, perhaps you/others could try <s>[Gnash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash_(software))</s>, a libre reimplementation of Flash. I have not used it, but apparently Gnash can run some Flash software without using Adobe's player. (For future readers: [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/) is probably a better choice than Gnash.)

Comment: Ruffle is also good as well, a lot of flash game sites use it. Unfortunately it does not support ActionScript3.

Comment: @SomeGuy Unlike Gnash, Ruffle's getting active development; it will probably support AS3 by… 2024? 2025? Unless development stops, you don't have _too_ long to wait.

Comment: Adobe *certainly* will not allow it because it opens the door to huge liability threats. They have removed that piece of [censored] software for a reason.

Comment: Adobe has a webpage for contacting them about distributing the flash player: https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution.html

Comment: BlueMaxima's Flashpoint is also very good and currently being developed.

Comment: @BumbleB2na unless I've missed something, that page isn't helpful for individuals because they just get sent to a page saying it's been retired when they click the download link.  Businesses can get a copy via a licensed 3rd party partner; I assume the usual exorbitant rates for enterprise software being sold to captive audiences will apply.

Comment: "when the only reason is for other people to be able to play games" - Definitely not the only reason. Flash was popular for lots of things. Games are one application, but in general you could use Flash for any kind of interactive software. As an example there were a lot of nice interactive educational programs available in the Flash heyday. Technically a sort of game but for education. Also if you want to develop a good open source Flash alternative, then of course you need to get your hands on the actual Flash Player that was used in the past in order to develop and test your open source one.

Comment: @Brandin yes, but games are the reason why OP wants to distribute Flash.

Comment: @Someone Well, I want to share my copy of the player because so many people miss Flash player, and I'm assuming that they miss Flash because they miss playing games on it because that's what I use Flash for. There's many other things that could be accessed if people got a copy of the OG flash player.

Comment: @SomeGuy even still, that's unlikely to count as fair use.

Comment: Lots of people miss the original Star Wars film (i.e. the one where Han shot first). And it's hard to find it now legally. Does that make it OK that you give me a copy? Of course that's a slightly unfair example because the Star Wars film is a work of fiction and there's a big commercial market for it, so fair use is very unlikely to apply.  Flash player is non-fiction, you could argue that your inclusion of it is transformative because it's needed to use the other software, and that your use does not affect the potential market because Adobe never charged for it before and never intends to.